# Equicontinuity on a compact metric space turns pointwise to uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I know that

*If $\{f_n\}$ is an equicontinuous sequence,  defined on a compact metric space $K$, and for all $x$, $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly.*

I'm having trouble proving this.  I see the same problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387560/equicontinuity-and-uniform-convergence-2) but am having trouble following the proof, particularly with part (3).

Can someone guide me through a proof of this result?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, we shall show that there exists an $n_0=n_0(\varepsilon)$, such that,
$$
n\ge n_0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lvert\, f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon,
$$
for all $x\in K$.

1. As $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous, there exists a $\delta>0$, such that for all $x,y\in K$:
   $$
   d(x,y)<\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lvert\, f_n(x)-f_n(y)\rvert<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}, \tag{1}
   $$
   for all $n\in\mathbb N$. If we let $n\to\infty$, then $(1)$ implies that
   $$
   d(x,y)<\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lvert\, f(x)-f(y)\rvert\le \frac{\varepsilon}{3},
   $$
2. Since $K$ is compact, it can be covered by finitely many balls of radius $\delta$, i.e., there exist $k\in\mathbb N$ and $z_1,\ldots,z_k\in K$, such that
   $$
   K\subset B(z_1,\delta)\cup\cdots\cup B(z_k,\delta).
   $$
3. As $f_n(z_j)\to f(z_j)$, for $j=1,\ldots,k$, we can find $n_0$, such that 
   $$
   n\ge n_0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lvert\, f_n(z_j)-f(z_j)\rvert<\frac\varepsilon 3,
   $$
   for all $j=1,\ldots,k$.
4. Finally, if $x\in K$ and $n\ge n_0$, then there exists a $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$, for which $x\in B(z_j,\delta)$, and hence
   $$
   \lvert\, f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert\le \lvert\, f_n(x)-f_n(z_j)\rvert
   +\lvert\, f_n(z_j)-f(z_j)\rvert
   +\lvert\, f(z_j)-f(x)\rvert<
   \frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}={\varepsilon}.
   $$
   [Ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.).

Comment: The last line of part 1, should that not have $n$'s on it?  Also, it seems compactness of the domain isn't necessary, is just a totally bounded domain sufficient?

Comment: @LoganTatham: Yes - corrected.

Comment: Using Cauchy's criterion, one can avoid the second implication in 1. The implication in 3. is modified and there is no need to consider $\delta/2$. It is only a pedagogical remark.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: You are right.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: can you perhaps describe what picture you might have in your head when you visualize what's going on?

Answer (score 5):

1. Since $f_n\to f$ pointwise, all uniformly convergent subsequences of $(f_n)$ have the same limit: $f.$
2. By [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces), $F:=\overline{\{f_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}}$ is a compact subset of $(C(K),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ hence a sequence in $F$ always has at least one subsequential limit and if it has only one, then it is convergent.

By this two points, $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: Where do we get that $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded in order to use Arzela-Ascoli?

Comment: @Integralfan  Uniform boundedness is not required in that theorem. Equicontinuity and pointwise boundedness are sufficient hypothesis.

Comment: Ah, I remember now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary but fixed.
Let
$$U_n := \{ x \in K \; : \; |f_k(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon \; \forall k > n \}$$

Then I claim $K = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}{U^\circ_n}$

Which can be easily proved by the equicontinuity assumption so because $K$ is compact and because $U_1 \subset U_2 \subset \dots \subset U_n \subset U_{n+1} \subset \dots $ there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K = U_n$

By the arbitrarity of $\epsilon$ I get the claim