# How do I show $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x)$ uniformly converges to $0$ on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

**Please read before posting a hint or answer as I know this question is probably elementary and there are standard hints and answers:**

---

Show that $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x)$ uniformly converges to $0$ on $[0,1]$.

We have to show that $\forall \epsilon \ \exists N \ \forall x \in [0,1]$ such that $n \ge N \implies |f_n(x)-0|<\epsilon$.

So, I must show $|x^n(1-x)| < \epsilon$ if $n \ge N$.

We see that $x^n(1-x)=x^n-x^{n+1}$ and since $x \in [0,1]$ then $|x^n(1-x)|=x^n(1-x)$.

So, we must show $x^n(1-x) < \epsilon$ if $n \ge N$.

I am having trouble beyond this and so I am trying to first go about it by showing pointwise convergence first, but I can't even do this. How do I even go about showing pointwise convergence?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649588/equicontinuity-on-a-compact-metric-space-turns-pointwise-to-uniform-convergence

Comment: $$ \max_{x\in[0,1]} x^n(1-x) \approx \frac{2}{e(2n+1)}.$$

Comment: Note that $nx^n(1-x)$ is not uniformly convergent from Jack's comment.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can you please explain How did you get that upper bound?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan: the maximum of $x^n(1-x)$ on $[0,1]$ is exactly $\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$ and the sequence $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1/2}$ is decreasing towards $e$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How did you prove that maximum of $x^n(1-x)$ on [0,1] as $\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$?. i tried using derivate. but I am not getting this as the upper bound.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan: given $f(x)=x^n(1-x)$, at which (non-zero) point $f'(x)=0$? Substitute and you are done.

Comment: Let me do the differentiation again and  try to prove $f''(x)<0$. @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan: what is the purpose of computing $f''(x)$? Your function is continuous and non-negative on $[0,1]$, so $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$ is obviously an absolute maximum.

Comment: I don't remember the result @JackD'Aurizio. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio $(x-\frac{1}{2})^{2 }+1$ is continuous and non negative on [0,1]. but $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is not absolute maximum. can you please explain your statement?

Comment: sorry! if I am annoying, I really don't understand your statement. please help me.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan: $f(x)=x^n(1-x)$ equals zero at the endpoints of $[0,1]$. $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$ is either a maximum or a minimum, and it obviously cannot be a minimum. Anyway, you may also compute $f''\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$ and check it is negative. It is not really needed, but it works.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I understand now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Recall Bernoulli's inequality: $( 1+x )^n \geq 1 + nx$ for $x \geq -1$.

Use this to show $x^n \rightarrow \infty $ for $x>1$ and hence $x^n \rightarrow 0$ for $x \in (0,1)$. Pointwise convergence is then obvious.

Once you have these pointwise bounds, you can then try to cook up a uniform bound using what we had above or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

By the AM-GM inequality, for any $n\geq 1$ and any $x\in[0,1]$ we have

$$\begin{eqnarray*} 0\leq x^n (1-x) = \frac{1}{n} x^n (n-nx) &=& \frac{1}{n}\text{GM}\left(x,x,x,\ldots,x,n-nx\right)^{n+1}\\&\color{red}{\leq}&\frac{1}{n}\text{AM}(x,x,x,\ldots,x,n-nx)^{n+1}=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and $\color{red}{\leq}$ holds as an equality only if $x=n-nx$, i.e. at $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$.
$$ 0\leq f_n(x)\leq \frac{1}{n+1} $$
then gives that $f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent to zero on $[0,1]$.

Comment: great one!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What is AM-GM inequality?

Comment: @AlJebr: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 0):

Pointwise convergence: Say, let $x=1/3$, do you know what value is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(1/3)$? If so, what if for any other $x\in[0,1]$, that is, for fixed $x\in[0,1]$, what is the value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** (pointwise convergence): How would you compute $\lim_{n \to \infty}(2/3)^n(1 - 2/3)$?  What about $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1)^n(1 - 1)$?  If you can find these limits, then you can surely find the pointwise limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}x^n(1 - x)$

**Hint** (uniform convergence): In terms of $n$, what is the maximum value attained by the function $f_n(x) = x^n(1 - x)$ over $[0,1]$?  What happens to this maximum as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Ok, I took the derivative and found the maximum value and now I see that as $n \to \infty$, $f_n(x) \to 0$. But how do I find $N$ which depends on $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** When $x\ge1-\epsilon$, show that $x^n\color{#C00}{(1-x)\le\epsilon}$.

**Hint 2:** When $x\lt1-\epsilon$ and $n\ge\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(1-\epsilon)}$, show that $\color{#C00}{x^n}(1-x)\color{#C00}{\le\epsilon}$.